# Проблема с display

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Есть два дива, по средствам Jquery cвойство display  меняется у объекта one при наведении мыши на img. Как мне сделать, что-бы two наследовал display у родителя (one)

```
      <img href="fdsafa">

<div id="one">
     <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если display у родителя меняется с none на block, то не нужно ничего делать с потомками. В иных случаях, придется сделать что-то вроде $('#one,#two').css('display', 'inline-block')

Answer (score 1):

display:inherit,
или почему же не сделать block так же для two при помощи js.